# Make title tags with extra spacing and bullets accessible

Tags: accessibility

Screen readers will read out things like `&nbsp` when formatting a `<title>` tag to be clean for people that can see.

```html
<title>contact&nbsp;&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;company</title>
```

Is there any way to make this less confusing?

Comment: Page titles should be semantic and consistent with common conventions. I've never seen a page title with a bullet before. Consider "Company Contact" or "Contact Company" instead. It's hard to tell which would be most appropriate without more context.

Comment: @Sean a huge number use things like bullets or |

Comment: I've never seen one with a bullet.

Comment: I'd question with stakeholders the importance of the bullet point. Screen readers and search bots aren't going to understand the semantic importance of it if people can't. "Contact company" is the option I'd go for since "Contact" is the purpose of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that it's technically invalid to include formatting like you're doing. That said, I'd question the utility of this approach for any visitor regardless of whether they are sighted or not.

If you want to make it less verbose, you could use unicode characters, but be aware that HTML does strip out extra whitespace, and the only way to make more than one consecutive space is to use the non-breaking-space (`&nbsp;`) character.

```
<title>contact • company</title>
```

As far as whether it's correct or not, the WHATWG HTML 5 specification states that the `<title>` element's [content mode is "Text"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-title-element), however the [definition of a Text content model](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#text-content) states that it also includes [Phrasing content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content-2).

The W3C HTML validator doesn't seem to complain about phrasing content being included in the title element. Search engines may handle this differently, and some may truncate your content based on length of characters or pixel widths.

Comment: I think the spec wording is a bit confusing here. When it says "Text... is also phrasing content" I think it means "Text is a type of phrasing content".

You can use Text where phrasing content is allowed but you cannot use non-Text phrasing content where only Text is allowed. That means (e.g.) `<span aria-hidden="true">` inside `<title>`will be rendered in full as a text node, rather than treated as a distinct (and AT-hidden) element.

Comment: @brennanyoung - That totally makes sense. After re-reading it, I see what you mean and I agree with you. I interpreted "Text... is also phrasing content" to be "Text includes Phrasing Content" which I don't think is true. Thank you for your interpretation. I learned something here.

Comment: This also helps to clarify a little:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories